# How can I find what kind of args and kargs a pandas function takes?

Tags: python, pandas

I was wondering how do I find what are valid kargs and args for a given function? For example in pandas there is this function cumin DataFrame.cummin(axis=None, skipna=True, *args, **kwargs); how do I know what *args does this function take? Where would I find the documentation?

https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.cummin.html . This link explains about axis and skipna but not args.

Thank you,

Sam

Answer (score 0):

As per the documentation of cummin:

> ***args**, ****kwargs**
> Additional keywords have no effect but might be accepted for compatibility with NumPy.

It doesn't take any specific arguments, the function only accepts them to avoid errors.